# How do I make Karma's auto-watch feature pause before running tests?

Tags: javascript, vim, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm running into what I think is a race condition between Vim saving files and Karma re-running my Jasmine unit tests. Here's a sequence of four test runs which demonstrates the symptom (I truncated the extremely long paths in the error log):

```
$ karma start karma.conf.js --auto-watch
[... snip a lot of coding and test running ...]
PhantomJS 1.6 (Linux) LOG: 'Running tests at 2013-08-14T08:19:57.252Z'
PhantomJS 1.6 (Linux): Executed 4 of 4 SUCCESS (0.307 secs / 0.013 secs)
PhantomJS 1.6 (Linux) LOG: 'Running tests at 2013-08-14T08:20:09.866Z'
PhantomJS 1.6 (Linux): Executed 4 of 4 SUCCESS (0.288 secs / 0.012 secs)
PhantomJS 1.6 (Linux) LOG: 'Running tests at 2013-08-14T08:20:14.366Z'
PhantomJS 1.6 (Linux) controller should have a breadcrumb after $routeChangeSuccess FAILED
        Error: No module: myapp.question
            at /home/rmunn/.../angular.js:1124
            at ensure (/home/rmunn/.../angular.js:1065)
            at module (/home/rmunn/.../angular.js:1296)
            at /home/rmunn/.../angular.js:2806
        TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'rootScope.$broadcast')
            at /home/rmunn/.../unit/controllersSpec.js:35
PhantomJS 1.6 (Linux): Executed 4 of 4 (1 FAILED) (0.312 secs / 0.014 secs)
PhantomJS 1.6 (Linux) LOG: 'Running tests at 2013-08-14T08:20:28.588Z'
PhantomJS 1.6 (Linux): Executed 4 of 4 SUCCESS (0.287 secs / 0.013 secs)
```

The only change I made to trigger these four runs was adding and removing whitespace from the `question.js` file; there were no substantial code changes, but run #3 failed where runs 1, 2, and 4 succeeded.

My Vim configuration is set up to keep backup files, and by default Vim keeps backup files by renaming the original file and writing a new one. (Except under certain conditions, which don't apply here). What I think is going on is that I'm triggering a race condition: Vim renames `question.js` (or whatever file I just edited), Karma detects that change and starts running tests, and because I have so few tests right now, the tests all run before the Linux process scheduler hands control back to Vim. Once Vim gets scheduled again, it writes the new contents of `question.js`, but by that point it's too late for the Jasmine test that depended on `question.js` existing and being non-empty.

I could possibly fix this by configuring Vim not to keep backup files, but I'd really rather not run that risk. There's a reason I use backup files, after all. So is there a way to tell Karma "when you detect a file change, pause for N milliseconds, then run the unit tests"? While it would be a brute-force solution, it *would* solve this particular race condition. Or if anyone has other clever ideas to offer, I'd love to hear those too.

Comment: Would setting `'backupdir'` to another, specific, directory help?

Comment: I already have `'backupdir'` set to ~/.vim/.backup (or rather, Jeremy Mack's [Vim Config of Champions](https://github.com/mutewinter/dot_vim) has set `'backupdir'` for me). The problem is that Karma is triggering on the original file "vanishing" when it moves into the backup dir, and then the tests sometimes run before Vim can get around to re-creating the file.

Comment: OK. It's probably off topic but it isn't a very good idea to use someone else's config.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This GitHub issue](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/199) discusses this issue as well. Vim can be configured to make backups by copying and then overwriting the original, instead of moving the original and writing a new file. While this isn't technically an answer to your question, it should be enough to solve your problem:

```
set backupcopy=yes
```

Vim will now edit the file in place, and Karma will detect this as "changed" instead of "removed".

See `:help 'backupcopy'` for details:

```
                        *'backupcopy'* *'bkc'*
'backupcopy' 'bkc'  string  (Vi default for Unix: "yes", otherwise: "auto")
            global
            {not in Vi}
    When writing a file and a backup is made, this option tells how it's
    done.  This is a comma separated list of words.

    The main values are:
    "yes"   make a copy of the file and overwrite the original one
    "no"    rename the file and write a new one
    "auto"  one of the previous, what works best
```

Comment: I had the same problem and this setting solved the issue. thks!

Answer (score 1):

From the [karma documentation](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.10/config/configuration-file.html), it seems there is an "exclude" option to remove some file pattern. If you modify your option to have a different name for backup and ignore Vim backup format, it should work properly.

But it will change your workflow somehow, you'll probably have to ignore the backup in your `.gitignore` as well.

Just a comment aside, I feel like with vim persistent undo (version >7.3), it seems that the backup file is a bit redundant. So maybe use,

```
set nobackup

set undodir=~/.vim/undodir
if (v:version >= 703)
   set undofile
   set undolevels=1000 "maximum number of changes that can be undone
   set undoreload=10000 "maximum number lines to save for undo on a buffer reload
endif
```

Comment: I already know that karma isn't triggering on the backup file, because the backups are going into my ~/.vim/.backup directory, which is not on karma's search path. (If that looks like a familiar setup, then yes, you're right: I'm using Jeremy Mack's [Vim Config of Champions](https://github.com/mutewinter/dot_vim) as a basis for my own vim config). It appears karma is triggering on the original file being deleted, not on the backup file being created. So unfortunately, I don't think your suggestion will work. Thanks, though.

Comment: @rmunn: keep us informed if you find a solution or workaround. It seems to be a problem that could be triggered by various tools.

Comment: Nothing found yet, and it will be a few days before I get back to this problem. We have a milestone release deadline coming up soon, and I'm working on other parts of the code to get it ready before deadline. Bugfixes are a bit higher priority for me at the moment than "my testing tools aren't behaving optimally". But once I do get back to this problem, I'll make sure to update this question if I find anything that works well.